# Control accessed on a thread other than the thread it was created on

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading

[image]

In brief: I want to load my form, then using a `Background Worker` fetch data from `Database`  and set the DataSource of some comboboxes.
In `DoWork` event I fetch data, and in `RunWorkerCompleted` event I set the datasources. The problem is cross-threading issues. What can I do to resolve this?

**I don't understand why setting DisplayMember is OK but in next line, setting ValueMember throws an exception**

Comment: Please post the code not a picture of it.

Comment: sorry @RichardSchneider, thanks for mentioning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you got it backwards.  The DoWork should be `FetchData` and DoWorkCompleted should be `BindComboBoxes`.

Comment: You're right :) In changing codes I copy pasted things and didn't pay enough attention. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the control's 'Invoke' method to run code in the same context(thread) as that control. Here is a simple example:

```
comboBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate{
       //Code to modify control will go here
            comboBox1.Text = "";
        });
```